# Why can't I login to test Facebook user accounts from the Android native app?

Tags: android, facebook, api, testing, authentication

I'm writing an Android app which makes use of Facebook for authentication. To test this I have written a script which creates a number of test user accounts using the guidelines [provided in the Facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/).

Each test user account comes with a fake email address and a password. It is possible to login to each test account via the main Facebook site using these details. All good so far.

However, If I try to login to any of my test user accounts using these details on the Facebook native Android app, or even via the m.facebook.com mobile site, I get a generic "An error occurred during sign in. Please try again later." error.

Has anyone else experienced this? Is there a box I need to tick somewhere to enable these test users for mobile app access? Or are test accounts restricted so that they cannot be used from a mobile device?

Has anyone had any luck logging into a test user account from a mobile device, in particular from Android?

All thoughts and comments greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've experienced this (same error message; it's unhelpful).  It's frustrating.  I will resort to OffBySome's solution if I find it necessary.  Technically, you can do almost anything since you can get your test users' access tokens.  The one thing you can't do?: Test login mechanics :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've ran into enough issues like this and others that I have just switched to creating full fledged fake accounts for testing against their guidance.  I just got sick of running into these gotchas.  I haven't ran into any issues in the past year + with the army of facebook accounts I have created.

Comment: It's getting trickier to do that. FB seem to have a whole bunch checks in place to detect fake account creation. I have to say I'm not hugely impressed with FB's support for mobile app developers. Seems like an afterthought.

Comment: Yes you just need to be even trickier about creating fake accounts. Make them seem as real as possible.

Comment: @bkaid I'm sorry but that doesn't work anymore - test users now have different tokens and with the new Facebook graph 2.5 you have to specify publish_actions. I've managed to log in with test user on Facebook app, go to settings on device (my case iPhone) - there i put in my test user info, then went into Facebook app and sign out and sign back in. but for my app i can't get it to sign in with test user, it just signs in with my account and thats it, I've tried everything. can anyone assist?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, I created test users, but cannot log on as them from the android native app on my android device. I have not tried the emulator.

I found a bug open on facebook site for something similar and added my weight on it. Hopefully they will look into it if many people report having the same issue.

To my mind, this is so important! This should be fixed if it indeed is broken.

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/403919519621830